# Partially meeting conditions and sorting by match rank

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table where very simplified data looks like the following (but it could include millions of rows with a lot more data in dozens of columns of different types):

```
+----+----+---+-----+
| ID |  X | Y |  Z  |
+----+----+---+-----+
|  1 |  1 | 1 | "a" |
|  2 |  1 | 0 | "a" |
|  3 |  0 | 1 | "a" |
|  4 |  0 | 0 | "a" |
|  5 |  0 | 0 | "b" |
+----+----+---+-----+
```

What would be the approach to select only the data with full AND MAYBE partial condition matching but up to a certain match rank, with the results sorted by that match rank?

E.g. when the condition is `WHERE ((X = 1) AND (Y = 1) AND (Z = "a"))` how would it be possible to get the following results in the following order:

```
+----+----+---+-----+-------+
| ID |  X | Y |  Z  | MATCH |
+----+----+---+-----+-------+
|  1 |  1 | 1 | "a" | 100%  |  <- 100% because all conditions matched
|  2 |  1 | 0 | "a" |  66%  |  <-  66% because X & Z matched but Y didn't
|  3 |  0 | 1 | "a" |  66%  |  <-  66% because Y & Z matched but X didn't
|  4 |  0 | 0 | "a" |  33%  |  <-  33% because Z matched but X & Y didn't
|  5 |  0 | 0 | "b" |   0%  |  <-   0% because nothing matched
+----+----+---+-----+-------+
```

Or being able to select up to a certain match rank, so with `WHERE ((X = 1) AND (Y = 1) AND (Z = "a")) AND (MATCH >= 25)` we'd only get the following:

```
+----+----+---+-----+-------+
| ID |  X | Y |  Z  | MATCH |
+----+----+---+-----+-------+
|  1 |  1 | 1 | "a" | 100%  |
|  2 |  1 | 0 | "a" |  66%  |
|  3 |  0 | 1 | "a" |  66%  | 
|  4 |  0 | 0 | "a" |  33%  | 
+----+----+---+-----+-------+
```

Or with `WHERE ((X = 1) AND (Y = 1) AND (Z = "a")) AND (MATCH >= 75)` to get:

```
+----+----+---+-----+-------+
| ID |  X | Y |  Z  | MATCH |
+----+----+---+-----+-------+
|  1 |  1 | 1 | "a" | 100%  |
+----+----+---+-----+-------+
```

- Due to the table having tens of millions of rows iterating over them wouldn't be possible for scalability reasons (but other required conditions could be passed to narrow down the results).
- The percentage values are for illustrative purposes only and aren't strictly required (the same applies for the looks of the `MATCH >= XX%` condition which would likely have to be represented differently).

I guess I'm looking for something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM xyz
WHERE (X = 1 AND Y = 1 AND Z = "a")
   OR (X != 1 AND Y = 1 AND Z = "a")
   OR (X = 1 AND Y != 1 AND Z = "a")
   OR (X = 1 AND Y = 1 AND Z != "a")
   OR (X = 1 AND Y != 1 AND Z != "a")
   OR (X != 1 AND Y != 1 AND Z = "a")
   OR (X != 1 AND Y = 1 AND Z != "a")
   OR (X != 1 AND Y != 1 AND Z != "a")
```

But it of course wouldn't necessarily sort them in the order of the match rank nor allow specifying the match rank (other than maybe programmatically generating the needed number of `OR` conditions which is also an option).

Comment: Are those columns integers?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for asking! No, not necessarily, updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can do the calculation in-line:

```
select t.*
from (select x, y,
             ((x = ?)::int + (y = ?)::int) / 2.0 as match
      from t
     ) t
where match = ?;
```

The `?` are placeholders for your values.

Comment: Haha, that's very clever and I suppose answers my question exactly but it isn't generic enough (I guess I simplified the data a bit too much as the columns could be of any type), I [tried to update the question to make it slightly more specific](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57292788/revisions). Thanks!

Comment: @MihailRussu . . . It is better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one way using JSONB to count the number of matches:

```
with vals (x,y,z) as (
  values (1, 1,'a')
)
select d.*, 
       (select count(*)
        from (
          select jsonb_build_object(k,v) 
          from jsonb_each(to_jsonb(v)) as t1(k,v)
          intersect
          select jsonb_build_object(k,v) 
          from jsonb_each(to_jsonb(d) - 'id') as t2(k,v) 
        )t
       ) as num_matches
from data d
   cross join vals v
where d.x = v.x
   or d.y = v.y
   or d.z = v.z
order by num_matches desc;
```

Not very pretty but at least the calculation of the number of matches is dynamic based on the number of columns of the "values" part.

returns:

```
id | x | y | z | num_matches
---+---+---+---+------------
 1 | 1 | 1 | a |           3
 2 | 1 | 0 | a |           2
 3 | 0 | 1 | a |           2
 4 | 0 | 0 | a |           1
```

---

If there are more columns that need to be ignored (not just `id`), you need to extend the `to_jsonb(d) - 'id'` to also remove the other columns - which makes this only partially "dynamic".

Doing this and calculating the percentage can all be put into a function:

```
create or replace function match_percent(p_values jsonb, p_row data)
  returns int
as
$$
  select ((count(*)::numeric / (select count(*) from jsonb_object_keys(p_values)))*100)::int
  from (
    select jsonb_build_object(k,v) 
    from jsonb_each(p_values) as t1(k,v)
    intersect
    select jsonb_build_object(k,v) 
    from jsonb_each(to_jsonb(p_row)) as t2(k,v)
    where t2.k in (select k from jsonb_object_keys(p_values))
   ) x;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

Then the query can be simplified to:

```
with vals (x,y,z) as (
  values (1, 1,'a')
)
select d.*, 
       match_percent(to_jsonb(v), d)
from data d
   cross join vals v
where d.x = v.x
   or d.y = v.y
   or d.z = v.z
order by match_percent desc;
```